# How can I put my icons at the bottom centre of the webpage?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-4

Is anyone here able to think of a way which I can put my icons `.chevron-row` at the bottom centre of each section of my webpage without using `position: relative`and `position: absolute` due to the impacts it has. [Site code](https://jsfiddle.net/qu8nushL/17/#&togetherjs=rRKkdCbfNd)

SECTION1

```
<a href="#part2">
     <i class="fa fa-chevron-down fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</a>
```

SECTION 2

```
<a href="#part3">
     <i class="fa fa-chevron-down fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</a>
```

SECTION3

```
<a href="#part1">
     <i class="fa fa-chevron-up fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</a>


<a href="#part2">
     <i class="fa fa-chevron-up fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
.chevron-row{   
color: white;
bottom: 0;
position: absolute;
width: 100%;}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/qu8nushL/20/

Answer (score 0):

Use a flexbox and align the icon at the end of it

```css
.section1 {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.section-content {
width: 100%;
}

.icon {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  align-self: flex-end;
}

.icon a {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="section1">
  <div class="section-content">
    <h1>Heading</h1>
    <p>Paragraph</p>
  </div>
  <div class="icon">
    <a href="#part2">
      <i class="fa fa-chevron-down fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
#part1,
#part2,
#part3 {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
}

#part1 {
  background: #39A0ED;
}

#part2 {
  background: #32322C;
}

#part3 {
  background: #36F1CD;
}

.chevron-row {
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  top: 90vh;
}

.chevron-row a {
  color: white;
}
```

[Here is code](https://jsfiddle.net/codeDesigne/qu8nushL/19/)